# "A WebService annotation is not present" exception

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, wsimport

I'm trying to call a web service. I used wsimport to create stub classes based on the WSDL. I created a small console app to test them in Eclipse, and this apps works correctly. I then moved these classes into a CMS I'm using (Day CQ 5.3), modified the package name accordingly, and created a small JSP page to test them. When I attempt to view the page, I get an error that says "A WebService annotation is not present on class package.name.ProductsSoap".

However, 1) ProductsSoap is an interface, not a class. 2) ProductsSoap does indeed have a WebService annotation. 3) There were no generated classes that implement the ProductsSoap interface.

What would cause this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use spring framework to consume your web service? You should have `spring-ws-core` and `spring-ws-core-tiger` in your classpath.